# How to run Linux commands in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, linux, shell

I want to run a Linux command in my Android app.
I mean I'm an Android programmer and I want to commit a command in my codes in Java which I'm writing in Android Studio.

For example this is what I want in my codes in Java in Android Studio:

```
ImaginarylinuxClass.theFunctionWhichRunsTheCommands("sudo apt-get update && git clone  && etc");
```

I hope I was able to say what I mean.

I tried to Google about it but it was all apps which they are Linux emulators like *termux* but it's not what I want actually.

Comment: I am not sure on what you mean, where do you want the code to be executed?
Are you trying to execute the command on a remote machine?
Are you trying to execute the command in the android shell?
what do you want to happen when you execute `ImaginarylinuxClass.theFunctionWhichRunsTheCommands("sudo apt-get update");`?

Comment: You cannot run UNIX commands on Android OS without any additional applications installed

Comment: What does additional installed apps do when I run "sudo apt-get update" in them ? i wnat to do the same in my app

Comment: I know they make a linux emulator and run commands as they make folders like dev , env etc. I just want to do the same in my app . I hope there should be an api for this

Comment: if you are thinking of running apt-get update for android apps, no.
android, is not a GNU/Linux system (it has a modified version of linux kernel), and it doesn't have aptitude or any such package manager to run from shell. this is the reason you found `Termux` during your research. it was created by the people who loved the idea of having `apt` or `yum` or `yay` in their palm top and to have strong operating system to fiddle with.

Comment: I may still have misinterpreted your question, may be a link to your source, or code snippet might help. Ie I still have difficulty understanding which app you want to update or where the command will run on.. would `/sbin/shutdown now` would shutdown your phone or the app?

Comment: Actually I want to make an app which works with metasploit in it .

Comment: "would /sbin/shutdown now would shutdown your phone or the app? "**the phone**

Comment: metasploit is a part of Termux (`pkg install metasploit`), I assume you are not planning to re-invent the wheel and want the metasploit to work within android itself rather than in an emulator, is that correct?

Comment: no . what termux does is that it lets me " as an user " to use metasploit . but my app will be communicating with metasploit with the commands and just give the results to the user . this is what I mean

Comment: If its necessary to build an emulator to have access to metasploit in an adnroid device , so help to build one in my android app

Answer (score -1):

Test this code man:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd sdcard/");
} catch (Exception e) {
    showMessage(e.toString());
}
```

Replace *"cd sdcard/"* for your Linux commands...

Comment: I used this code `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo hello > /storage/emulated/0/file.txt");
` but no file was created. And also there were no errors, i mean the catch block didn't run. My app has read, write external storage access.  **NOTE:** I'm on android 11